# Python Looping until max number is reached

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

my tool stops randomly and it seems like all threads are 'ghosts'.

How does it work: 
The tool loops until the max number of allowed threads at the same time are running, in this case 20. When a thread finishes it starts the next one.

Problem:
After like an hour of doing this, the tool is stuck at 20 Threads running but nothing happens anymore.

Thanks in advance everyone!

```
maxthreadcount = 20
while True:
    if threading.active_count() < maxthreadcount:
            threading.Thread(target=Dealer).start()
```

Dealer:

```
def Dealer():
  print("thread started")
  return
```

Comment: Why not have your loop as `while threading.active_count() < maxthreadcount:`? Your code is going to keep looping and doing the if-statement test indefinitely.

Comment: Is that all the threads are doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to terminate previously created threads after their job (`print` command in this case) is done.

Take a look at this example from [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/start-and-stop-a-thread-in-python/):

```
class CountdownTask: 

    def __init__(self): 
        self._running = True

    def terminate(self): 
        self._running = False

    def run(self, n): 
        while self._running and n > 0: 
            print('T-minus', n) 
            n -= 1
        time.sleep(5) 

c = CountdownTask() 
t = Thread(target = c.run, args =(10, )) 
t.start() 
... 
# Signal termination 
c.terminate()  

# Wait for actual termination (if needed)  
t.join()
```

I think you should call `self.terminate()` after doing the `print`. Something like below:

```py
class Dealer():
    def __init__(self):
        self._running = True

    def run(self):
        print("thread started")
        return self.terminate()

    def terminate(self):
        self._running = False
```

**Edit**

I also believe you can make use of python's `ThreadPool` to this extent. Instead of spawning threads yourself, you might be able to reuse threads after their assigned task is over, for the new tasks.